# Volume of Region Bounded by $y = \sqrt{x}$ and $y = 18-x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, solid-of-revolution

I haven't a clue why I'm having so much issues solving this problem. The two curves are $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=18-x^2, x \ge 1$, and rotated about the $y$-axis.

If I'm not mistaken, I need to use the shell method. In that case, the volume integration formula is $\int 2\pi x f(x)dx$.

So my thickness is $dx$, my height is $f(x)$, I believe my range is from $1$ to $\sqrt{18}$ ($1$ because $x \ge 1$ and $\sqrt{18}$ because $0 = 18-x^2$).

So I integrate $2\pi \cdot x \cdot x^{1/2} dx$ and get $(2/5)x^{5/2}$ from $1$ to $\sqrt{18}$, but that isn't even close to the answer.

I've been working on this problem far too long and am getting brain fog.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Rotated about the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be adding "a lot of" silinders of height $dy$ with radius $r(y)$. It is of the form $$V = \int _0^2 S_1(y)dy + \int _2^{18} S_2(y)dy  $$
The two curves meet at $y=2$ (for $x=4$) so for $y\in [0,2)$ the radius of the circle is determined by $y=\sqrt{x}$, therefore $r_1(y) = y^2, y\in [0,2)$.
The radius is determined by $y=18-x^2$ for $y\in [2,18]$ hence $r_2(y) = \sqrt{18-y}, y\in [2,18]$.

Our volume is therefore
$$\pi\int_0^2 y^4dy + \pi\int_2^{18} (18-y)dy\tag{1} $$

If $x\geq 1$ is assumed, then we need to subtract some volume. To picture this, draw a vertical axis at $x=1$ and subtract the volume which is obtained by revolution of the piece to the left of $x=1$. We compute  the volume similarly so obtain
$$\pi\int_0^1 y^4dy + \pi\int_1^{17} dy + \pi\int_{17}^{18}(18-y)dy \tag{2}$$
Volume of interest is obtained by subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$.

Comment: I just calculated a correct answer using your logic. I'm just quite confused how such hoops are required to jump through. This chaining of volumes doesn't really fit with the chapter material. It was my understanding that the volume being calculated was only from x range 1 to sqrt(18), and only the region under both curves. My head hurts.

Comment: I am making the assumption the piece rotating around the y axis is the one bounded by $x=0$, $y_1,y_2$. Augmented with the extra condition that $x\geq 1$. I merely apply the additivity property of the integral.

Comment: It makes sense to me now that I see the solution. I suppose I was too close minded, as all previous problems were simple volumes of areas under two curves. The text even says for this specific problem "bounded by the graphs of the given equations". Maybe I just misinterpreted the question. Thanks!

Comment: When you write $dx$ it may be that you are rotating around the $x$ axis. You must pay attention around which axis the piece is being rotated. Results will be very different, indeed.
Should you have rotated around the $x$ axis, the radii of the circles will be $y$-values (the 'height' of the graph).

Answer (score 1):

Note that [the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ and $y = 18-x^2$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tqhhboppue) shows that these two curves meet at $x = 4$ and $y = 18-4^2 = \sqrt{4} = 2$.  Write out explicitly $f$ in the question body.

$$f(x) = 18-x^2-\sqrt{x} \quad \forall\,x \in [1,4]$$

\begin{align}
\text{Required volume of revolution}
&= 2\pi \int_1^4 x f(x) dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_1^4 (18x - x^{3/2} - x^3) dx \\
&= 2\pi \left[9x^2 - \frac{x^{5/2}}{5/2} - \frac{x^4}{4} \right]^4_1 \\
&= 2\pi \left[ 9(4^2 - 1^2) - \frac{64}{5} + \frac25 - \frac{4^4 - 1^4}{4} \right] \\
&= \frac{1177\pi}{10}
\end{align}

Comment: My book gives an answer of $1177pi/10$, so perhaps my bounds are wrong?

Comment: @awbasham (1) *Which* book?  (2) Use `\pi` instead of `pi` to input $\pi$.  (3) If you have new bounds, you're welcome to start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the region and set up the integral as below:

[image]

$$V = 2\pi\int_{1}^{4} (18-x^2-\sqrt{x})xdx$$

$$V = 2\pi \int_1^4 x (18-x^2) dx - 2\pi \int_1^4 x \sqrt{x} dx $$
$$== 2\pi \left[ 9(4^2-1) - \frac{4^4-1}{4} -\frac{64}{5} +\frac25  \right]$$

$$ V = \frac{1177\pi}{10}$$